# c# accessing methods based on condition

Tags: c#

I have application whose have 2 parts (2 separate application): designer (call it ConfigurationBuilder) and executer (Call it ConfigurationExecutor).

There is class library object who consist of Manager class and it is shared by the above applications. Within ConfigurationBuilder user can run custom code where it will consume methods of Manager class and these methods will create objects. (serialize it and create DbTables)

ConfigurationExecutor user consume methods of Manager class and these methods will create rows on tables.

Now, I want to prevent user consuming API in ConfigurationBuilder which is sepcific to ConfigurationExecutor and vise-versa.

Appreciate for sharing best practices.

Thanks.

Comment: some kind of class diagram would likely help here? This is very hard to read as it stands

Comment: This question confuses me... Building an API means, others should use it too. Furthermore have you heard of `internal` and `private`?

Comment: Why don't you split your Manager class into BuildManager and ExecutionManager?

Answer (score 1):

Create two interface with separate methods 
Suppose this is Your Manager class

```
class Manager()
{
 Method1();
 Method2();
 Method3();
 Method4();
 }
```

Divide methods in interfaces

```
IMethodsForConfigurationBuilder
 {
  Method1();
  Method2();
 }


IMethodsForConfigurationExecutor
 {
  Method3();
  Method4();
 }
```

Implement these interfaces in on Manager

```
Manager : IMethodsForConfigurationBuilder,  IMethodsForConfigurationExecutor
{
 Method1();
 Method2();
 Method3();
 Method4();
 }

// Now in your ConfigurationBuilder  class 

 { IMethodsForConfigurationBuilder  Manager = new Manager();}

//and in your ConfigurationExecutor classs call

IMethodsForConfigurationExecutor Manager = new Manager();
```

Comment: This looks like better idea. I will test and come back. Thanks.